# How do you wait on a main queue completion handler?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, closures, completionhandler

What I'm trying to do is sequentially execute a for loop where I wait for the completionHandler() before starting the next iteration.

- I have to wait for the completion handler to return before iterating
- Guaranteed return to completion handler
- I'm trying to wait in a lower priority queue synchronously

Code:

```
// we're on the main queue
for index in 0..<count {
    var outcome: Any?
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "\(index) iteration")
    // this will access a UI component and wait for user to
    // enter a value that's passed to the completion handler
    funcWithCompletionHandler() { [weak self] (result) in
        outcome = result
        semaphore.signal()
    }
    // wait here for the completion handler to signal us
    queue.sync {
        semaphore.wait()
        if let o = outcome {
            handleOutcome(outcome)
        }
    }
    // now, we iterate
}
```

I've tried a lot of other solutions I see here, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Never wait until on the main thread. And it’s no better to synchronously dispatch that wait to another queue. Eliminate the semaphores and call the completion handler in the completion block of the original asynchronous call. Or if there’s some reason you think you can’t do that, explain why and we can offer alternatives.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "call the completion handler..."  More info, the funcWithCompletionHandler() closure is escaping.  It opens a modal child view controller that calls the completion handler on dismissal with the outcome value the user entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer working with a background group, you can make an instance of it on your class like this: 
  `var group = DispatchGroup()`

```
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.group.wait()

       // this part will execute after the last one left
       // .. now, we iterate part
    }


    for index in 0..<count {
        var outcome: Any?
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "\(index) iteration")



        funcWithCompletionHandler() { [weak self] (result) in
            if let strongSelf = self {
                outcome = result
                strongSelf.group.enter() // group count = 1
            }

        }

        queue.sync {
            if let o = outcome {
                handleOutcome(outcome)
                self.group.leave()
                // right here group count will be 0 and the line after wait will execute
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this was what I was trying to do, but another UI problem made it unclear this was working.